# Field norm calculation on ElasticSearch array fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's the mapping for one of the fields in my index:

```
"resourceId": {
    "type": "string",
    "index_analyzer": "partial_match",
    "search_analyzer": "lowercase",
    "include_in_all": true
}
```

Here are the custom analyzers used in the index:

```
"analysis": {
        "filter":  {
            "partial_match_filter":  {
                "type":  "ngram",
                "min_gram":  1,
                "max_gram":  50
            }
        },
        "analyzer":  {
            "partial_match":  {
                "type":  "custom",
                "tokenizer":  "whitespace",
                "filter":  [
                    "lowercase",
                    "partial_match_filter"
                ]
            },
             "lowercase":  {
                "type":  "custom",
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter":  [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

This field will contain an array of strings, which are the multiple IDs that a resource can have (it can have multiple IDs due to different systems calling each resource by a different id).

Now let's suppose that **resource #1** has has three IDs:

```
resourceId: [3]
    0:  "ID:MATCH"
    1:  "MATCH"
    2:  "ID:ALT"
```

And that **resource #2** has only one ID:

```
resourceId: [1]
    0:  "ID:MATCHFIVE"
```

And let's suppose that we run this query against my index:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "resourceId:ID\\:MATCH"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'd like is for resource #1 to show up first, since its array contains an exact match. **However, resource #2 is the one coming on top**;

When I used the *explain* parameter on the query request, I saw that the *tf* and *idf* scores where the same for both resources. **However, the *norm* score was lower for resource #1**.

My theory is that since resource #1 has three items in the array (which I assume are concatenated together during indexing), the field is considered larger, and thus the norm value is decreased. When it comes to resource #2, it has only one item (and it's shorter than the concatenation of the other array), so the norm is higher, bumping the resource to the top.

My question, therefore, is: **when calculating the score, is it possible for the norm calculation to only consider the size of the item that matched in the array?**

For example: the search for "ID:MATCH" would find the exact match on resource #1 on resourceId[0]. At this point, all other items in the array would be put aside and the *norm* would be calculated based on that single item (resourceId[0]), showing a perfect match. As for resource #2, the norm would be lower, since the resourceId field would be larger.

If this isn't possible, would there be workarounds to get the exact match to the top? Or maybe I'm completely off on my theory?

Comment: Hi @Victor , did you find a solution for this use case ?